# Cast to pointer to array of runtime-determined size

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, g++, runtime

Is this cast allowed by C++ standard? I was able to compile it with g++ 5.4 (running in linux), but not with g++ 4.2 (running in OSX).

```
char* ptr;
char (*img)[width][3] = (char (*)[width][3])ptr;
```

'width' is an integer determined in runtime. g++ 4.2 throws:

```
cannot initialize a variable of type 'char (*)[width][3]'
  with an rvalue of type 'char (*)[width][3]'
```

Which doesn't make any sense to me.

(PS: I was actually surprised when this first compiled)

**EDIT**

Small code that compiles in g++5.4

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    char* ptr;
    int width;
    std::cin >> width;
    char (*img)[width][3] = (char (*)[width][3])ptr;
}
```

The Mac that couldn't compile this with g++4.2 is not with me now, so I can't reproduce the error. As shown in the comments by @xskxzr with Compiler Explorer, [it compiles in g++4.1](https://godbolt.org/g/e81Kzx). However, [it doesn't compile in clang](https://godbolt.org/g/7XoGWP), throwing the same error I stated earlier:

```
<source>:9:12: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char (*)[width][3]' with an rvalue of type 'char (*)[width][3]'
    char (*img)[width][3] = (char (*)[width][3])ptr;
           ^                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

The questions are:

How is that output error interpreted?

Is it possible that g++ versions are quite different for OSX?

Comment: It [can compile](https://godbolt.org/g/bUwHE3) even with gcc 4.1.2. gcc supports variable length array as an extended feature. I guess you have used some command options to disable this feature. In addition, even if variable length array is supported, the conversion is still undefined behavior because of strict aliasing rules.

Comment: Can we have a piece of code that actually compiles? The above certainly doesn't in gcc g++ 7.0, nor in clang

Comment: I just edited and added a full code. @xskxzr I wasn't aware of the strict aliasing rules, and I just read a bit about it. From what I understand, the compiler optimizations can mess things up if you have pointers of different types to the same memory, am I right?
PS: I'm quite sure I didn't have any special command options on that g++4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation failure on the Mac is probably due to a a Clang bug (so `g++` ran Clang there, not GCC).  It has been observed before:

- [Issue with variable length arrays and C++: differences between g++ and clang](https://marc.info/?l=cfe-dev&m=146972302305434&w=2)

Variable length arrays are a GNU extension to C++, and Clang is supposed to support it, too.

At least on some versions of Clang, it is possible to get this to compile by introducing an explicit `typedef` for the variable length array type:

```
typedef int (*vla)[width][3];
vla img = (vla) ptr;
```

Comment: Great answer. I don’t understand what you mean by “g++ ran clang”. Aren’t they two different compilers?

Comment: Apple ships only a very old version of GCC, which isn't very useful anymore. Apparently, there is a toolchain selection tool `xcode-select` which controls what runs when `g++` is invoked. (I'm not a Mac user.)